# google avd and 3g turn on

Tags: c#, java, android, c++, android-emulator

I don't know how to turn on 3g in my google avd emulator.

I select Settigngs->Wireless network->mobile network-> then there is only 2g and others that are not 3g related.

Any one can help me turn on 3g in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

check mobile network > data enable
that's what 3g is: data

Comment: Thank you but I still have a x in the triangle next to 3g

Answer (score 0):

in Mobile Settings it should look like this to enable 3G (2.3.3 android emulator btw):

- Data Enable [x]
- Data Roaming []
- Access Point Names
- Use only 2G Networks []
- Network Operators